# Runtime Error while allocating an array on the stack

Tags: c, arrays, stack, runtime-error, long-integer

```
int main() {
      long long int n, m, j, l, a[1000000000][1000000000];
      int k, i;
      scanf("%lld", & n);
      scanf("%lld", & m);
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (l = 0; l < m; l++) {
          a[j][l] = 0;
          printf("%d\n", a[j][l]);
        }
      }
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (l = 0; l < m; l++) {

          printf("%d\n", a[j][l]);
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

When I run this i always get a runtime error.Can anybody please suggest me a solution to overcome it??? I need this for a competetive programming question where a ChessBoard may have 1000000000*1000000000 squares and I need to perform multiple operations with it.

Comment: I am a bit too lazy to count the zeroes, but you seem to be allocating at least 400 petabytes of memory. That's probably a bit much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in most implementations, you can not create local variables that big.

Do you really have 10000000000*10000000000 = 100000000000000000 bytes of memory?

On most systems the limit is somewhere between 64k and 10mibyte. Certainly not any where near the size you are trying to make a[][].

You need to use `malloc` to try and allocate memory. Local variable are made on a stack during run time, you are running out of memory for your stack, crashing your program.

Comment: I doubt that using `malloc` is going to help the situation :)

Comment: You never know maybe he has a 128bit computer with a full address space of ram ;-)